# Javascript TypeError: undefined is not a function when removing array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to remove elements from an array using Javascript and Angular Js when the user clicks on a button.

It works fine when there are 2 or more elements in the array, but unfortunately when it comes to removing the last array I get this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at k.$scope.delete
```

This is the code I'm using to remove the array elements.

```
  $scope.delete = function(item){
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
    $scope.items.splice(index,1);
  };
```

Working example here.

http://jsbin.com/tulaloliyi/3/edit?js,console,output

Comment: `$scope.delete = function(item){ delete $scope.items[item.id]; }`

Comment: In your working example, `array` is a javascript plain object, and `array.items` is also a javascript plain object.

Comment: In your working example replace `delete $scope.items[item.id]` with your own code, it is working for me without any error.

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari yes it works only when there is one item left, but gives an error if there are multiple items and doesn't delete any. my code works when there are multiple items, it deletes all the items until the last item is left, but breaks when there is only 1 item.

Comment: Don't know if i am missing something but i am able to delete all the items.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Change your remove button to this:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="delete($index)">Remove</button>
```

And your delete function to this:

```
$scope.delete = function(index){
    $scope.items.splice(index,1);
  };
```